# Java streams: How to map grouped items (return Map<Long, List<Mapped-Item>> instead of Map<Long, List<Original-Item>>)?

Tags: java

I have this query:

```
  public List<RCouponDetailEntity> getAllDetailsByCouponId(final List<Long> couponIds) {
        return entityManager.createQuery("SELECT rc from RCouponDetailEntity rc where status='Active' and rc.rCoupon.id in (:couponIds)",
                RCouponDetailEntity.class).setParameter("couponIds", couponIds).getResultList();
    }
```

And then :

```
   Map<Long, List<RCouponDetail>> details = rCouponDetailDAO.getAllDetailsByCouponId(couponIds).stream()
                        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(RCouponDetail::getRCouponId));
```

In RCouponDetailEntity i just want to get column code, so what i want to achive is to return

```
 Map<Long, List<String>
```

where key is `couponId` and List is string of codes from `RCouponDetailEntity` .
Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 1):

[`groupingBy(classifier, downstream)` collector](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-java.util.stream.Collector-) does exactly this:

```
import java.util.stream.Collectors.groupingBy;
import java.util.stream.Collectors.mapping;
import java.util.stream.Collectors.toList;

...

Map<Long, List<String>> codesByCouponId = 
    rCouponDetailDAO.getAllDetailsByCouponId(couponIds)
   .stream()
   .collect(
       groupingBy(
           RCouponDetail::getRCouponId, // classifier
           mapping( // downstream: 
               RCouponDetail::getCode, // map grouped items
               toList() // collect mapped grouped items to list
           )
       )
   );
```

Comment: problem is that when i try to add imports i get message:
The import java.util.stream.Collectors.toList cannot be resolved

Comment: this is weird, please double-check spelling, Java version etc. Use can also import `Collectors` use qualified names: `Collectors.groupingBy`, `Collectors.mapping`, `Collectors.toList`.

Comment: jdk1.8.0_121, that is im using